# How to show a currency pound sign in posting post in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i really had an issue with showing the £ symbol while posting in facebook using the open graph.

let say I have this string as my post

```
$message = "For sale at &pound; 20.00";
```

will what it display in my facebook timeline is exactly the same string, should it be convert to pound sign.

I also using this "£" symbol but the result is "�"

anyone having same issue? Please, your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `\u00A3` for the symbol `£`?